# My iphone 4s turns on while charging, but once on it turns off

Tags: battery, iphone, charging, charger

Recently my phone died and I plugged it in, and like usual it turned itself on. But I noticed that once the phone was turned on it wasn't charging. I tried a new charger, but all the chargers I have create the same outcome. I think this may be due to my phone and not the charger, does anyone know why it doesn't want to charge while on?

Comment: Battery dying? Socket dirty? Hard to diagnose without seeing it. Take it to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad battery to me. You can get a new battery and everything you need to change it at a website called iFixit for like $30 shipped, (don't worry, for a 4S, a battery replacement is super easy, it's just 4 screws and pulling the battery connector off of the logic board).